# I got None for an empty list:reference table Field, but I want it display "" or "-" in my grid results

Tags: list, lambda, web2py

"represent=lambda v, r: '-' if v is None else v" works fine for a normal Field but not for a list:reference Field like next:

db.define_table('projecto',
Field('localizacao_fk', 'list:reference concelho')

How can I resolve this issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `NULL` values (which will be represented as `None` in Python), the column may contain empty lists, which the `DAL` will convert to `[]` (empty lists are stored as the string `||` in the database, not as `NULL`). So, your `represent` function should check for both types of empty values:

```
represent=lambda v, r: '-' if v in (None, []) else v
```

Or more simply:

```
represent=lambda v, r: v or '-'
```